# Calculate the average per row per set of columns

Tags: r, matrix

What I would like to do is the following, given a matrix, for example: `mat <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 4)` and a set of combinations of the columns `c_w <- combn(c(1,2,3,4), 2)`. I would like to calculate the average per combination. So for the first combination, we have `rowMeans(mat[,c_w[,1]])`, for the second `rowMeans(mat[,c_w[,2]])`. So far so good and I can wrap this in a for-loop and then use row combine to combine the results in a nice results matrix. However the problem is performance, if possible I would like to do this in a vectorized manner. So my question is:

can we do this without for loops in the R-code?

**edit**
I would like to have it in Matrix form, where each column stands for the mean of each set. However this can also be achieved with some small additions to Arun's code. Please turn the comment into an answer in order for me to give you points :).

Thanks

Comment: The array approach is btw a bit faster I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `FUN` argument in `combn` to do the `rowMeans` directly within the `combn` step after subsetting the columns of 'mat' with the column index derived from `combn`

```
 combn(1:4, 2, FUN=function(x) rowMeans(mat[,x]))
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #[1,]    3    5    7    7    9   11
 #[2,]    4    6    8    8   10   12
 #[3,]    5    7    9    9   11   13
 #[4,]    6    8   10   10   12   14
```

Or another option if we got the `combn` output would be to `split` by the `col` of 'c_w' and loop through the 'list' elements with `sapply`, subset the 'mat' with the numeric index and get the `rowMeans`

```
 sapply(split(c_w, col(c_w)), function(x) rowMeans(mat[,x]))
 #     1 2  3  4  5  6
 #[1,] 3 5  7  7  9 11
 #[2,] 4 6  8  8 10 12
 #[3,] 5 7  9  9 11 13
 #[4,] 6 8 10 10 12 14
```

Or a third approach would be concatenate (`c`), the column index from `c_w` and use that to get the columns of 'mat', create a `array` with the specified dimensions.  Here, we know that 4 is the number of rows of 'mat', 2 as the 'm' specified in the `combn` and `6` as the ncol of 'c_w'.  Loop with `apply`, specify the MARGIN as '3', and get the `rowMeans`.

```
 apply(array(mat[,c(c_w)], c(4,2,6)), 3, rowMeans)
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #[1,]    3    5    7    7    9   11
 #[2,]    4    6    8    8   10   12
 #[3,]    5    7    9    9   11   13
 #[4,]    6    8   10   10   12   14
```

Or as @A.Webb mentioned, `apply` would be more natural for a matrix like `c_w`

```
 apply(c_w,2,function(i) rowMeans(mat[,i]))
```

Comment: `apply(c_w,2,function(i) rowMeans(mat[,i]))` is a bit more clear to me at least.